# Cannot import file based on user input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import

I have small vue.js app.

I want to import specific json based on user input.

```
import content from "@/posts/posts/" + new URL(location.href).searchParams.get('id') + ".json";
```

Every time I do this I get an error on the first plus sign.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:37)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> import content from "@/posts/posts/" + new URL(location.href).searchParams.get('id') + ".json"
```

But when I try to import it with one string like this:

```
import content from "@/posts/posts/0.json";
```

it works.

Comment: Try this https://dmitripavlutin.com/ecmascript-modules-dynamic-import/ alternatively require should also work, but not sure about the best practices.

Comment: @NoName Thank you! It is solved my problem, can you pleas put this in answer for me to be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dynamic imports refer to this [article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/ecmascript-modules-dynamic-import/)
alternatively, you could also use `require` instead of `import` but not sure which one is recommended.